# Transaction with Sequelize doesn't work

Tags: sql, node.js, transactions, promise, sequelize.js

I want to build a simple webform where you can enter a persons firstname, lastname and select multiple groups for this person (but one for now)

I'm using node.js and sequelize to store the person in a MariaDB -Database.

Sequelize created the tables *Persons*, *Groups* and *GroupsPersons* according to the defined models.

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

var Group = sequelize.define("Group", {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}

var Person = sequelize.define("Person", {
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
}


Person.belongsToMany(Group, {as: 'Groups'});
Group.belongsToMany(Person, {as: 'Persons'});
```

Because creating the person and assigning it into a group should be handled atomically in one step I decided to use a transaction, shown in the docs here:
http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/transactions/#using-transactions-with-other-sequelize-methods

```
var newPerson = {
    firstName: 'Hans',
    lastName: 'Fischer'
}
var id = 3    // group

sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    return Person.create(newPerson, {transaction: t}).then(function (person) {
        return Group.find(id, {transction: t}).then(function(group){
            if (!group) throw Error("Group not found for id: " + id);
            return person.setGroups( [group], {transction: t});
        })              

    });
}).then(function (result) {
    // Transaction has been committed
    // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback is
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
    // Transaction has been rolled back
    // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback is
    console.error(err);
});`
```

But for some reason neither `function (result) {..` for success nor the function in catch gets called. However, the complete SQL queries of the transaction were generated except COMMIT, so nothing was inserted into the db.

If I put it like this 
    `return person.setGroups( [], {transction: t});`
the transactions succeeds, but with no inserts into *GroupsPersons* of course.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Shouldn't your Group model use [`hasMany`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/index.html?highlight=hasMany) instead of `belongsToMany`?

Comment: what would be the benefit?

Comment: You should consider opening an issue at the issue tracker of sequelize - from first looks your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{transaction: t} was misspelled, it works now